# Load malformed XML file into string javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, http

I have a server response that is roughly of the form:

```
<A>...</A><B>...</B><C>...</C>
```

I am trying to load it using the code:

```
xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
xhttp.send("");
```

However I get the error

```
junk after document error
```

I plan on loading the malformed XML doc, and parsing out the info I need using regexes (i am not going to be parsing XML using regexes btw!!!)

How can I load this response as a string?

Changing the response from the server is not an option. And it must be in javascript.

Thanks

Comment: You're missing some info here. What is the server running in order to produce the output? Where does the error comes from?

Comment: @alexandernst: The response is of the form:
[12:31:44.175] "<?xml-stylesheet href=\"chrome://global/locale/intl.css\" type=\"text/css\"?>\r\n<parsererror xmlns=\"http://www.mozilla.org/newlayout/xml/parsererror.xml\">XML Parsing Error: junk after document element\nLocation: file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/xml.xml\nLine Number 1, Column 36:<sourcetext>&lt;ACTION&gt;GETSYSTEMRESOURCES&lt;/ACTION&gt;&lt;RESPONSE&gt;Success&lt;/RESPONSE&gt;&lt;RESPONSEDATA&gt;\n-----------------------------------^</sourcetext></parsererror>"

Comment: This error is from FF trying to parse some invalid XMl and saying so. What is the *actual* server output? Open FireBug (or equivalent) and see what exactly is the server sending. Maybe append it to the question.

Comment: The output is sensitive, that isn't something I can do

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming you know what you're doing

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'www.mydomain.com/generatexml',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log("XML received!", data);
    ...
    RegExp...
    ...
  }
});
```

(Using jQuery)